# Calling 'layered navigation' attributes into a static block

Tags: attributes, layered-navigation, ce-1.9.2.2

So to explain what i'm trying to do:

*I want to take my filterable results such as brand or product type that you would find in the left navigation to a static block.*

I'm no coder, but I figured I was in the right area using code like this inside a static block.

```
<reference name="content">
<block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav" template="..." />
</reference>
```

I'm convinced it doesn't need to be difficult, pulling attributes like that onto a static block but the more I look the more confused I get. What I'm effectively trying to do is just make customers more aware that they can narrow down their results.

This is the page in question, as you'll see i've added some basic images that link to filterable results but I'm considering using the brands or pet type in the static block just to make it a little easier for customers.

http://naturalpetsupply.co.uk/dogs-4/dogfood.html

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried my solution?

Comment: Try my answer and let me know Its working or not

Answer (score 0):

You can add below code block in static block via below code.

```
{{block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav"  template="yourtemplate.phtml"}}
```